# Efficient cross domain web API like Twitter Facebook Google etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api

I have recently been experimenting with building a cross domain web api, and wow has it been a bumpy journey. I have not had any problems with modern browsers such as Chrome, FF and Safari. The problem is with IE, which requires you to use XDR as opposed $.ajax when making cross domain calls. First Question: **If I was using Backbone.js, what is the recommended way of making cross browser and cross domain ajax calls?**

Another problem I had with IE was that when you make cross domain ajax requests, IE has a bunch of restrictions and limitations such as "Only text/plain is supported for the request's Content-Type header" - [a link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx). Therefore in my case, I was unable to bind to my model using the MVC C# framework, unless I bind it manually.

Anyway my second and last question is: **How do companies like Instagram, Facebook, and Twitter go about building their API's?** I am not looking for a complete guide, but just want to know how difficult it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSONP**

The current standard is using [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). It is basically a trick to send a JSON payload wrapped in a single JavaScript function, the browser treats it like a script file and executes it.

**CORS**

Moving forward the way to go is [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Sadly browser support (IE) isn't there yet and there are still some implementation differences between the modern browsers that do implement it.

**HTTP Method Overloading**

Some APIs overload `GET` and `POST` request using `X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT` or `?_method=PUT`.

**easyXDM**

A number of API providers implement [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/). This tends to be used more when they provide a JavaScript API or widget API where developers load their JS and integrate it directly in to the frontend code.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but does JSONP only allow GET requests. If so how do you satisfy the REST verbs required by backbone.js? How do the above mentioned deliver a cross browser API?

Comment: Yes. JSONP is GET only. I updated my answer with a couple addition tricks devs use.

Comment: Concerning CORS support in browsers, I think it looks rather promising, see http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Disclaimer: I'm maintaining http://enable-cors.org and might be considered slightly biased towards CORS ;)

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I'm in love with CORS myself but when implementing it a few months ago there just isn't enough IE support for use unless you are ok with losing those users. Safari also had some implementation diferences. That may have improved but Safari doesn't update as fast as Chrome.

Comment: You forgot to mention iframe and postMessage. Works quite well for IE 8+

Comment: @tkone: that is what easyXDM uses a lot of the time.